# Why Google Pixel phone kernel does not need CONFIG_MMC?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, google-pixel

On the page https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/boot-times Google explains it removed CONFIG_MMC from the kernel for the Google Pixel phones. However don't most mobile devices use emmc for flash memory?

Comment: I'm curious; what makes you think _most_ mobile devices use emmc for flash memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to iFixit I can see now that the Pixel Phone uses UFS instead of eMMC, over the past two years mobile devices are transitioning to UFS I see.

Google Pixel Phone 2016: Samsung KLUBG4G1CE 32 GB Universal Flash Storage (UFS) 2.0

Samsung Galaxy S7: Samsung KLUBG4G1CE 32 GB MLC Universal Flash Storage 2.0

Samsung Galaxy S8: Toshiba THGBF7G9L4LBATR 64 GB UFS (NAND flash + controller)

Nexus 6P: Samsung KLMBG4GEND-B031 32 GB eMMC 5.0 NAND Flash

Nexus 5X: Toshiba THGBMFG7C2LBAIL 16 GB eMMC 5.0 Flash Memory